# Map equivalent for list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, iterable-unpacking, map-function

```
[foo(item['fieldA'], item['fieldC']) for item in barlist]
```

Is there a map equivalent for this?

I mean, something like this:

```
map(foo, [(item['fieldA'], item['fieldB']) for item in barlist])
```

but it doesn't work. 
Just curious.

Comment: Something missing from my answer that disqualifies it as acceptable? I see you accepted then unaccepted again.

Comment: Sry about it. I just doing more tests before accepting. The confusing part is that starmap generates an iterator, and i have to learn more about that.

Comment: You can call `list()` on the generator to consume everything into a list object. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for [`itertools.starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
from itertools import starmap

starmap(foo, ((item['fieldA'], item['fieldB']) for item in barlist))
```

`starmap` applies each item from the iterable as *separate arguments* to the callable. The nested generator expression could be replaced with an [`operator.itemgetter()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for more mapping goodness:

```
from itertools import starmap
from operator import itemgetter

starmap(foo, map(itemgetter('fieldA', 'fieldB'), barlist))
```

Like all callables in `itertools`, this produces an iterator, not a list. But if you were using Python 3, so does `map()`, anyway. If you are using Python 2, it may be an idea to swap out `map()` for [`itertools.imap()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) here.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing beats [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap), like Martijn explained. But if you like to use only `map`, then you can simulate what `starmap` internally does, like this

```
map(lambda fields: foo(*fields), ((it['fieldA'], it['fieldC']) for it in bars))
```

Or you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), like this

```
map(lambda fields: foo(*fields),(itemgetter("fieldA","fieldC") for item in bars))
```

`*fields` is nothing but unpacking the values which we received with `itemgetter("fieldA","fieldC")`. So, the value of `fieldA` will be the first argument to `foo` and the value of `fieldC` will be the second argument to `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this.

```
bar = lambda x: foo(x['fieldA'], x['fieldC'])
map(bar, barlist)
```

Still, it is rather inadvisable to use map, not list comprehension.